# How to clean up menu li by removing all attributes, but keep `class="active"` for the current menu item?

Tags: php, wordpress

Using wordpress, making a simple menu; unordered list with li, and no attributes present to make the HTML look cleaner. However, the active li (depending on the page the user is on) should have a `class="active"`.

I've tried changing the priority parameter of the `add_filter` in `functions.php`.

Here's the first block of code that removes the class attribute.

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'my_css_attributes_filter', 10, 1);
function my_css_attributes_filter($var) {
    return is_array($var) ? array() : '';
}
```

Here's the 2nd block, which has the same hook, `nav_menu_css_class`, and the same priority parameter, `10`, as the first block.

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'special_nav_class' , 10 , 2);
function special_nav_class($classes, $item){
    if( in_array('current-menu-item', $classes) ){
                    $classes[] = 'active ';
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

I would like to know how to make my li look like this when on the active page:

```
  <li class="active"></li>
```

If I remove the `add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'my_css_attributes_filter', 10, 1);`, the `active` class is present, but with all the other mess:

```
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type_archive menu-item-object-news current-menu-item menu-item-42 active"> </li>
```

Comment: Why are you binding two functions to the same hook in the first place? In your second one, you are _adding_ the `active` class to the array, isn’t that the place where you should simple return an array that contains nothing but that class?

Comment: Try if you can get something simple like this working as desired, `return in_array('current-menu-item', $classes) ? ['active'] : [];` - return either an array containing only one item containing `active`, or a completely empty array.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works.

Comment: @04FS I've also used this, however I could do with adding a class if there are children. Any ideas how to add that?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you 04FS, here's what worked:

This removes the `id` attribute.
    add_filter('nav_menu_item_id', 'my_css_attributes_filter', 10, 1);
    add_filter('page_css_class', 'my_css_attributes_filter', 10, 1);

```
function my_css_attributes_filter($var) {
    return is_array($var) ? array() : '';
}
```

This removes all the values for `class` attribute except `active`:

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'special_nav_class' , 10 , 2);
function special_nav_class($classes, $item){
    return in_array('current-menu-item', $classes) ? ['active'] : [];
}
```